# Command Line Install Only

Tags: system-installation, arm

I want to install Ubuntu on a small ARM-based device (TrimSlice) to control a bitcoin mining device, but I have no need for a GUI.  I don't want Xorg, I don't want Unity, no Nouveau, none of that.  I want the ability to install .deb packages using apt-get and I want Ubuntu because I'm familiar with it.

I already had Ubuntu 12.04 on this device previously, but upgrading Ubuntu caused the machine to fail to boot.  I want to start over with whichever version makes sense, but mostly I just want only a command line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the server edition, and don't choose to install a desktop environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have an enviroment with terminal only the you should choose ubuntu server :

You can Download it from This [LINK](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) , burn it on dvd ,and start installation.

[Here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/step-by-step-ubuntu-12-04-precise-lamp-server-setup.html)  step by step installation guide for Ubuntu server installation .

When you finish this should be your login screen , type your account password that you write in installation , and begin working .

You should be good in commands :)

[image]

Comment: nux, your image shows version 10.10.  Do you feel the version matters?  I'm inclined to use an LTS version, or is there some sort of benefit to using 10.10?

Comment: i would prefer 12.04 , its a google pic

Comment: i edit it man don't be sad :)

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to Ubuntu netiso. It can be burn in a CD or dropped in an USB. It won't install anything extra, only what you ask for to install, so no extra scruff. You can look for the one that suits your needs [in the wiki page.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)