# Ubuntu install command-line only?

Tags: command-line, 14.04

I am trying to install ubuntu 14.4 on a computer (actually into QEMU emulator) which does not use unity or any GUI, and only a command line which looks like the "terminal" application in fullscreen. I checked out [Command Line Install Only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428585/command-line-install-only), but I do not want server features, just ubuntu desktop features without the desktop. How can I do this, or possibly is there a way to remove the "server" from ubuntu server?
EDIT:
Ubuntu server appears to be only available for 64-bit machines. I am planning to run it within QEMU Emulator on a 32-Bit Toshiba Satellite machine running Ubuntu Desktop 14.4.

Comment: When you install the "server edition" it gives you the **option** of installing common server specific tools, but you are free to exercise the option of installing none of them. Otherwise the base system between the desktop and server edition is practically the same, except that the server does not install a DE by default (which is what you want). Doing an minimal install from the ubuntu server edition would be your best bet.

Comment: I need something 32 bit. UServer is 64 bit only.

Comment: absolutely not true, they have both x86 and x64 editions [link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Server does not install the Desktop environment, and I believe is what you are looking for.  You are not required (or forced to) run any server services after installing Ubuntu Server.

Comment: @user3053430 Just wanted to comment many server OS's are very similar to the desktop package. The tools are usually what make the two types different. I am unsure why you wish to do command-line only Ubuntu, but you can always just do `Ctrl+Alt+F1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Ubuntu Minimal CD. There is the text based installation and once you get to the software section, do not chose any of the desktops. Once the installation finishes you will have a machine without X windows, only the command-line.